# react-native-material-ui throw an Unexpected token export

Tags: reactjs

I tried to use react-native-material-ui but got an "Unexpected token export"
I couldn't tell anything wrong with the statement...all the references are correct and the code format is correct too

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "redux-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "lint": "eslint src"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "reactjs",
    "hot",
    "reload",
    "hmr",
    "live",
    "edit",
    "webpack"
  ],
  "author": "Mark Qian",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.20",
    "babel-eslint": "^4.1.3",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.0.15",
    "eslint": "^1.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.6.2",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2",
    "history": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "google-map-react": "^0.24.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "paradux": "^1.2.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.8",
    "react-data-grid": "^2.0.30",
    "react-data-grid-addons": "^2.0.30",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-mapbox-gl": "^1.9.1",
    "react-motion": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.43.4",
    "react-native-material-ui": "^1.9.0",
    "react-pure-render": "^1.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "react-tabs": "^0.8.2",
    "react-toggle-display": "^2.1.1",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.3.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1"
  }
}
```

and here is the code

```
import { BottomNavigation } from 'react-native-material-ui';
```

and here is the error

```
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:4554)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at fn (bundle.js:87)
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:4548), <anonymous>:11:30)
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:4548), <anonymous>:77:27)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:4548), <anonymous>:78:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:4548)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at fn (bundle.js:87)
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:4014), <anonymous>:35:21)
```

Here is the code of react-native-material-ui/index.js

```
export * from './src/index';
```

and here is the react-native-material-ui/src/index.js

```
import * as COLOR from './styles/colors';

export { COLOR };
export { default as ThemeProvider } from './styles/ThemeProvider.react';
export { default as RippleFeedback } from './RippleFeedback';
// components
export { default as ActionButton } from './ActionButton';
export { default as Avatar } from './Avatar';
export { default as Badge } from './Badge';
export { default as Button } from './Button';
export { default as BottomNavigation } from './BottomNavigation';
export { default as Card } from './Card';
export { default as Checkbox } from './Checkbox';
export { default as Dialog } from './Dialog';
export { default as DialogDefaultActions } from './Dialog/DialogDefaultActions.react';
export { default as Divider } from './Divider';
export { default as Drawer } from './Drawer';
export { default as Icon } from './Icon';
export { default as IconToggle } from './IconToggle';
export { default as ListItem } from './ListItem';
export { default as RadioButton } from './RadioButton';
export { default as Subheader } from './Subheader';
export { default as Toolbar } from './Toolbar';
export { default as Snackbar } from './Snackbar';
```

Maybe version conflict with "react": "^15.3.0"?

Any idea?

thanks